# Composer fails to install Piwik on Windows

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php, matomo

Tools:

- Windows 8.1 Pro
- Composer
- piwik
- xampp v3.2.1

I've installed piwik and composer and I'm testing them out in xampp. I'm going through this guide found at: http://developer.piwik.org/guides/getting-started-part-1

However, I've come across an issue. When I'm trying to run the command to install the 3rd party libraries, I'm getting this error:

> c:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\piwik>php C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar install
>
> 'misc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   Script misc/composer/clean-xhprof.sh handling the pre-install-cmd event returned with an error
>
> [RuntimeException]
>     Error Output: 'misc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>     operable program or batch file.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Piwik's composer configuration will run shell scripts to install xhprof if possible. But it seems it is incompatible with Windows.

I had created a new issue on the tracker: https://github.com/piwik/piwik/issues/6493

**Edit**: I have reproduced it. In the meantime you can use:

```
php C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar install --no-scripts
```

I have tried it and it works on Windows. Remember you also need to have git installed, else some dependencies cannot be fetched.

**Edit 2:** I have fixed the bug in master, it will be included in the next release, probably 2.9.0.